# Bitcoin: error parsing json in bashscript to send BTC using sendmany command

Tags: bitcoind, bash

I am simulating a bitcoin network on my machine for which I have written a bash script to simulate the transactions between the nodes. When I use the `sendmany` option of `bitcoin-cli` to send transactions I am getting an json parsing error reported by `bitcoin-cli`.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX_NODES=2
MY_PATH=/home/ubuntu/test
CLIENT=/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli

declare -a addr

function fcomp() {
        /usr/bin/awk -v n1=$1 -v n2=$2 'BEGIN{ if (n1>n2) exit 0; exit 1}'
}

json="'{"

#get addresses to send
for ((i = 1; i <= MAX_NODES; i++));
do
    addr[$i-1]="$($CLIENT -regtest -rpcport=$((16500 + $i)) -datadir=$MY_PATH/$i/ getnewaddress myaccount)"
    if [ "$i" -lt "$MAX_NODES" ]
    then
        json="$json\"${addr[$i-1]}\":0.00001, "
    else
        json="$json\"${addr[$i-1]}\":0.00001"
    fi
done

json="$json}'"
echo $json

#loop to send money to other nodes
for ((i = 1; i <= MAX_NODES; i++));
do
        balance=`$CLIENT -regtest -rpcport=$((16500 + $i)) -datadir=$MY_PATH/$i/ getbalance`
        if fcomp $balance 0.002; then
                $CLIENT -regtest -rpcport=$((16500 + $i)) -datadir=$MY_PATH/$i sendmany myaccount $json
    fi
done
```

echo json output:

```
'{"mj2FrDhEomSzyQtRoGY78oVRPcQs5L5o95":0.00001, "mkxnkT3kx9dsFS8V3qYydpL1o5F5MfwCvM":0.00001}'
```

This gives me an error as:

```
error: Error parsing JSON:'{"mj2FrDhEomSzyQtRoGY78oVRPcQs5L5o95":0.00001,
```

I tried all possible combinations of quotes, double quotes and escape sequences but failed. If I copy paste the output of `echo $json` to a manual `bitcoin-cli sendmany` command it works perfectly fine.

Comment: 1) Are you using the same shell to run the when you're copy/pasting as when you're using the script? 2) Try  removing the space after the comma on the line `json="$json\"${addr[$i-1]}\":0.00001, "` That seemed to help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your echo output:

```
'{"mj2FrDhEomSzyQtRoGY78oVRPcQs5L5o95":0.00001, "mkxnkT3kx9dsFS8V3qYydpL1o5F5MfwCvM":0.00001}'
```

Then you have too many quotes.  When you run echo, you should see:

```
{"mj2FrDhEomSzyQtRoGY78oVRPcQs5L5o95":0.00001, "mkxnkT3kx9dsFS8V3qYydpL1o5F5MfwCvM":0.00001}
```

That's because the shell strips off the outer set of quotes; it does that when you send the JSON to bitcoin-cli too.  Because you have the quotes there in the echo output, it implies that they're there in the bitcoin-cli command, so what you're sending Bitcoin Core looks like a JSON string rather than a JSON object.

---

This isn't asked in your question, but you might also want to look into the Debian/Ubuntu packages and commands named `jshon` and `jq`.  These help you process JSON in shell scripts.  Because they understand JSON, they tend to be a lot more robust the `sed` and `awk`.  I don't know if you need them for this script, however.